# Pandas calculate cumsum of values between dates (from another df)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

first time posting here.
I want to find the cumulative sum of values in a column by MachineID (im thinking that groupby should be used for this?) for datetime ranges found in another df. Minimal code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

#Define first dataframe
d1 = {'DateTime': [dt.datetime(2019, 10, 1), dt.datetime(2019, 11, 15),dt.datetime(2019, 12, 1),dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)], 'MachineID': [1, 1, 3, 1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

#Define second dataframe
d2 = {'DateTime': [dt.datetime(2019, 10, 5), dt.datetime(2019, 11, 5),dt.datetime(2019, 12, 5),dt.datetime(2020, 1, 5)], 'MachineID': [1, 1, 3, 1], 'ExperimentalValue':[5.5, 7.1, 3.9, 113]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

The sample dataframes look like this:

```
df1
Out[65]: 
    DateTime  MachineID
0 2019-10-01          1
1 2019-11-15          1
2 2019-12-01          3
3 2020-01-01          1

df2
Out[69]: 
    DateTime  MachineID  ExperimentalValue
0 2019-10-05          1                5.5
1 2019-11-05          1                7.1
2 2019-12-05          3                3.9
3 2020-01-05          1              113.0
```

For each MachineID i want to find the cumulative sum of the values in the column ExperimentalValue for dates in between the DateTimes found in df1 for that paticular machine. E.g. for MachineID = 1 the first DateTime range found in df1 is [2019-10-01; 2019-11-15], using this date range to find the cumulative sum for ExperimentalValue in df2 for machineID 1 should yield:

```
    DateTime  MachineID  ExperimentalValue  CumSum
0 2019-10-05          1                5.5  5.5
1 2019-11-05          1                7.1  12.6
2 2019-12-05          3                3.9  3.9
3 2020-01-05          1              113.0  113.0
```

Notice that only the first two lines get summed (in line 2) since these are the only with the same MachineID and in the same datetime range from df1.

I cannot figure out how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the CumSum re-starts each time the MachineID changes, so we cannot group by MachineID.  I created a new column called block_id, to track this change.  I started with the original definition of df2:

```
# MachineID on current row vs previous row
df2['block_id'] = df2['MachineID'] != df2['MachineID'].shift(1)

# cumulative sum of boolean increases each time the MachineID changes
df2['block_id'] = df2['block_id'].cumsum()

df2['CumSum'] = df2.groupby('block_id')['ExperimentalValue'].cumsum()

print(df2)

    DateTime  MachineID  ExperimentalValue  block_id  CumSum
0 2019-10-05          1                5.5         1     5.5
1 2019-11-05          1                7.1         1    12.6
2 2019-12-05          3                3.9         2     3.9
3 2020-01-05          1              113.0         3   113.0
```

You would probably want to drop the block_id column, but I left it in to show the logic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is a nice trick. However, I am still unsure of how I can get the cumsum between the dates given in df1 for each MachineID?

Answer (score 0):

Here is additional info, on working with the first data frame.

- I assume each row means a machine starts (or stops) on a given date.
- The goal is to get start time and stop time on the same row.
- If there's no stop time, then the machine is still operating.

```
# start with df1 as defined in original post
#
# a machine cycles: start -> stop -> start -> ...
# make a label to identify `start event` vs `stop event`
df1['range'] = ((df1['MachineID'] != df1['MachineID'].shift(1)).astype(int))

# identify the stop/start pairs
df1['idx'] = df1['range'].cumsum()

# re-shape the data frame
df1 = (df1.set_index(['MachineID', 'idx', 'range'])
       .squeeze()     # Data Frame -> Series
       .unstack()     # range (start/stop) to column label
       .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={1: 'start', 0: 'end'})
      )

# end date missing?  machine still going
df1['end'] = df1['end'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('2099-12-31'))

# clean up and print
df1.columns.name = ''
print(df1)

   MachineID  idx      start        end
0          1    1 2019-10-01 2019-11-15
1          1    3 2020-01-01 2099-12-31
2          3    2 2019-12-01 2099-12-31
```

Now you can combine df1 and df2.  E.g., for a given row in df2: are we in the first start/stop cycle, the second cycle, ...